# Handle Paypal payments via PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I want to create a web service where people need to have an active monthky/weekly subscription via paypal in order to access it.

A few years ago I implemented simple one click payments via the paypal ipn but is this still the best way or is there something else? I saw Paypal opened a new dev section.

I have tried countless php classes to simplify paypal IPN implementation but most were unstable or broken.

Is there any PHP class you can recommend for handling payments with paypal, especially subscriptions?

What is the best way to handle subscriptions? Will paypel send a notification for every now month when the payment is send and I should I renew the membership for 1 month then?

Or does paypal send a notification when a member cancels the membership and it should remain active till that point?

Answer (score 0):

i have worked quite a bit with paypal straight buying, but not subscriptions. but yes, the IPN way is still the way. and you need the ipn listener of course too. i imagine with subscriptions is very similar to normal buying, as you mentioned they probably send you a confirmation each month that the amount has been paid, and probably send you a notification when someone cancels their subscription - but check - you can read all that stuff in their documentation.

in the last year or so the only thing thats changed with the IPN is that you need this Curl certificate saved on your server for the IPN listener class to work properly (cant remember whats it called but can find out for you) - the certificate is easily found online.

i can paste the full IPN Listener class for you here if you like